# Putting timestamp on the data fetched from remote sqlserver to local mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jdbc

I am pulling data from remote sqlserver to local mysql server using jdbc .

In remote sqlserver server I have 2 columns

```
Name  Count
```

In local mysql I have  3 columns made

```
Name  Count  Time_stamp
```

time_stamp as **datetime datatype**

I am pulling data using below insert code segment,

```
while (rs.next()) {
                    String zoneName = rs.getString("Name");
                   int zonecount = rs.getInt("Count");



                    String insertSql = "insert into occupancy.occupancy_phase_2(Name,Count)values('"+zoneName+"',"+zonecount+")";                 
                   pstmt = con2.prepareStatement(insertSql);
                    pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

I want to add timestamp to the insert query at every run .

How can i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function of mysql to get the currentdate and insert it (Here I am assuming the database server to be in same timezone as application server)

You can use following query string

```
String insertSql = 
"insert into occupancy.occupancy_phase_2(Name,Count,Time_stamp)values('"+zoneName+"',"+zonecount+", Now())";
```

Also you directly give values instead of specifying the column

```
String insertSql = 
    "insert into occupancy.occupancy_phase_2 values('"+zoneName+"',"+zonecount+", Now())";
```

**NOTE:**

While using prepared statement use the `PreparedStatement` instance to set the query parameters, like below

```
String insertSql = 
        "insert into occupancy.occupancy_phase_2 values(?,?, Now())";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(insertSql);
ps.setString(1, zoneName);
ps.setInt(2, zonecount);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the type "timestamp" in the mysql table and it will be automatically filled in by mysql.

for example,

```
create table if not exists blammo
(
  Name varchar(250),
  Count int,
  last_updated timestamp
);
```

then just insert values into Name and Count.

for example,

```
insert into blammo
(Name, Count) values ('kapowzie', 17);
```

The timestamp field will update every time the row changes unless you set it to it's current value.  There is a way to define the column to disable the automatic updating, but I can't remember the syntax for that.

For details, check the [MySql Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html)